# Self-disciplined deletion of a good answer on the wrong question

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Last night I discovered that once upon a time I totally misread a question and gave an answer that just didn't fit the question that was being asked. I know, I know, how could that even happen? But I got a bunch of votes.

Part of me thinks that I should be self disciplined, earn that disciplined badge, and delete the somewhat popular answer.

But it is a good answer, and it provides important information (or at least I and a few voters think so).

Should I delete it as not an answer, or should I leave it so someone else can benefit from it even if it's not really in the right place?

EDIT:

The answer I had in mind was [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17166/5). I'm now having second thoughts.  Comments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest: You wrote your answer in response to a real question, albeit a question which hadn't actually been asked. So ask that question. (Ask it properly, [avoiding the temptation to skimp on question quality](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/581).) Then repost your answer on that new question, and delete it from its current spot. (I thought that mods could move answers, but apparently this is not possible.) You may be able to take the opportunity to polish up your answer while you're about it.

Comment: Good idea. +1. And, no, mods can't move the answer. Doubtless there's a way to do so server-side, but I don't think the people who can do so wish to be bugged to. Just copy-paste and delete.

Comment: Mods can only move *all* answers at once.

Comment: Trig, @msh210, please see my edit. What do you think of the answer and its relationship to the question?

Comment: @SethJ, looks deletionworthy (not an answer).

Comment: Well, the answer's gone now, and I missed it. I'll assume it was delitionworthy. @SethJ.

Comment: Aww, sorry man. I may take your suggestion, though, in which case you can evaluate it then.