# Where can I find the reason for a question being deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers, deleted-questions

Just recently I answered a question about saying anenu in a case where one drank but didn't eat the whole day.

I answered the question, it was accepted by the OP, and I got like 6 upvotes. Now, looking at my profile, it's as if it never took place. No question, no answer, and no rep. for the answer.

Is there a way I can find out what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was removed because it violated the site rules in a way that necessitated its removal, and your (good) answer was unfortunately also therefore removed. Nothing to do about it, I'm afraid. I'm sorry you wasted your time writing an answer; don't let this deter you from writing others, as it's the kind of thing that happens but rarely.

That answers you about this particular question. More generally, once you have 10,000 reputation points, you can [see any deleted post](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

**Edit:** After consultation among the moderators, it's been decided that the question you asked about no longer needs to be deleted. It's now been restored, along with your answer.

Comment: Is there a simple way to tell that the question violated the site rules, so that I don't end up answering a similar quotation?

Comment: Not in a case like this one, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there really no hint you can give me? It seems like the original poster might have violated something, but not the question itself. In that case shouldn't the poster be banned but the question left alone?

Comment: I flagged one of his comments as *rude or abusive* because he called someone "retarded" now I'm left wondering if I "shot myself in the foot"

Comment: @ABochur Calling someone "retarded" is something that somebody else would have flagged, even if you hadn't.

Comment: @ABochur If you are particularly proud of research or writing you did that went into the now-deleted answer, you can always [post a well-written question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/306/2) that asks for that information and then self-answer it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses true, but I feel weird posting something that was just there and saying "hey please vote for me!" even though that's what this post might come across as. I'm not going to ask for the inside story for the deletion, but I'm almost positive that if I ask the same question now, with the same wording, it would get down-voted and closed as unclear, but it will not be fully deleted. That's why I suspect that the poster was the problem and not the post, and therefore he should be banned but not the post. I'll try to stop now :) thank you all.

Comment: @abochur If you post quality Q&A which is interesting and well written, you deserve to "ask" for votes. Sharing your knowledge with the community is valuable and acceptable.

Comment: @ABochur (btw, if we're talking about the same person, I flagged the "retarded" comment too).  I am totally in support of re-asking the deleted question as your own, with a self-answer.  There's nothing to be embarrassed of, and I'm sure you could re-ask it all that much better...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות  thanks for the encouragement :) I'm scared to post about anenu in case it will be taken as a security threat :) :)

Comment: Thanks for restoring it